# How Load Dockpanel from resource dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, dockpanel

I want to load a dockpanel control to an wpf window. the dockpanel control is on a resource dictionary file and that is merged in the window I want to use it. I want the c# code that can add this dock panel to a existing dockpanelhost control on the window dynamically upon a button click event. Please help me by providing the c# code implementation

Regards

Comment: You are probably using the wrong tool for the job, you probably want to put the DockPanel inside a Style or a template (DataTemplate or ControlTemplate depending on usage) - maybe even a UserControl if you want design time support (and don't put the UserControl inside a resource dictionary).

Comment: In that case, how can I use that control template inside my dockhost panel ? can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your DockPanel from resources like that:

```
var dockPanel = FindResource("DockPanelKey") as DockPanel;
```

Later add this line to insert dockPanel to for example grid:

```
m_Grid.Children.Add(dockPanel);
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Can you also please tell me how can I implement event handler on that resource dictionary controls as it isn't supporting enve handling attribute there? Also, I can't use it in design mode. How to do that please?